# Detect 403 or 404 in page.tpl.php

Tags: 7, theming

I'm looking for a **working solution**, to **detect a current 403 or 404 state** from within a template (page.tpl.php) in Drupal 7.

Unfortunately, Drupal seems to be unable to handle error pages.

Comment: Could you tell us what have you tried to get that working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If my assumption is correct, then you are looking for the way to handle 404 and 403 pages.

If that is the case,

> Goto **configuration**->**Site information**, there you can specify your own page for handling **404** or 
>   **403** pages.

For that particular page, you can write tpl file like `node--type--nid.tpl.php`